# как в списке убрать кавычки

Tags: python-3.x

Господа помогите плз, я начинающий, я получил список, в нем каждое слово в кавычках, как мне сделать, чтобы этот же список слов был без кавычек

```
import re
a = """По мнению Рубина, слова которого приводит Defense News, саудовская система ПВО не смогла обнаружить низколетящие
 ракеты и беспилотники, поскольку ее датчики отслеживали цели только над горизонтом. Кроме того, Саудовская Аравия имеет
  большую территорию, что также усложняет защиту воздушного пространства мнению."""


c = re.findall("[а-яА-Я\-]{1,}", a)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак, потому что там нет кавычек. Эти кавычки не входят в элемент списка, а означают, что данный элемент - строка. Они не являются частью списка.

Comment: большое спасибо, теперь ясно